# Todo App data structure using Cloud Firestore and React

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Considering I'm using Cloud Firestore and React, which one of the data structures below would be the best for a simple ToDo app?

I'm using the list of ToDos as an array in my React state.

**OPTION 1**

- todos (collection)

  - todo-list (document)

    - todo-list-content (array field)

      - "ToDo 1"
      - "ToDo 2"
      - "ToDo 3"

[image]

**OPTION 2**

- todos (collection)

  - todoId1 (document Id auto generated)

    - message: "ToDo 1"
  - todoId2 (document Id auto generated)

    - message: "ToDo 2"
  - todoId3 (document Id auto generated)

    - message: "ToDo 3"

[image]

I'm guessing Option 2 is the right choice, correct? Can anyone elaborate why that is?

Using Option 1 I would get the array straight away to pass to state, instead of having to iterate over the QuerySnapshot object in Option 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are guessing right, Option 2 is the right choice but this is not because you would get the array straight away to pass to state it is because the documents have limits. So there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. When we are talking about storing text, you can store pretty much but as your array getts bigger, be careful about this limitation.

If you are storing large amount of data in arrays and those arrays should be updated by lots of users, there is another limitation that you need to take care of. So you are limited to 1 write per second on every document. So if you have a situation in which a lot of users al all trying to write/update data to the same documents all at once, you might start to see some of this writes to fail. So, be careful about this limitation too.

So storing todos as documents in a collection is the best choice because there are no limitations. You can store as many documents as you want.